# can I embed a GWT panel in a grails app to render a url?

Tags: javascript, gwt, grails

I need to show the contents of a JavaScript(ed) url on my grails app. I wonder if a GWT panel will do the trick...

Comment: What is a Javascript URL? I don't understand.

Comment: Pekka, I meant a URL that contains JavaScript content.

Comment: but what kind of content, and show in what way? There are several ways this could be interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Panel`s accept `Widget`s as content, never URLs.

If you want to execute some JavaScript, make a JSNI function and call it.  If you're trying to bring up a URL in a pane, use a `Frame` widget, which is implemented with `<iframe>` tags.

Comment: Riley, I need to show the contents of a given URL that contains JavaScript elements, not actually execute JavaScript.